# Integer programming: Constraint on binary variable based on parameter value

Tags: integer-programming, constraints, mixed-integer-programming

I have a set of employees $E$ that I want to allocate to a set of rooms $R$, with indices $e$ and $r$ respectively. A binary variable $x_{er}$ is 1 if an employee $e$ is allocated to a room $r$, 0 otherwise. Each room has a priority for each employee, given by the parameter $V_{er}$, which is an integer value. Each employee has a prioritized preferred list of rooms, i.e. employee #2 might prefer room 3 first, room 5 second and room 1 third.  How can you ensure that no employee is assigned to a room over an employee with a higher priority for that room, represented as a constraint for an integer program?

**Additional comments**

The problem is to be solved as a minimization problem, where the objective is to allocate each employee to a room with as high preference as possible, without violating the constraint I am describing above. An employee getting its second preferred room is punished with a cost $W2$, getting its third preferred room is punished with a cost $W3$ and so on, where $W3$ > $W2$.

Comment: Is the priority list for each employee also influential in the problem? I.e. should we care about what each employee desires?

Comment: Yes, the objective is to assign all employees to a room with as high preference as possible. An employee getting its first choice is not punished, but getting its second is punished with $W1$ and getting its third choice is punished with $W2$. The problem is solved as a minimization problem. Please see additional comments above.

Answer (score 1):

You can enforce the rule with a linear "conflict" constraint $$x_{e_1,r_1} + x_{e_2,r_2} \le 1$$ if $V(e_1,r_1) < V(e_2,r_1)$ and $V(e_2,r_2) < V(e_2,r_1)$.

Comment: Not 100% sure what the part _ and (2,2)<(2,1)_ implies? Could you elaborate a bit more, please? Because the goal is to allocate employees to rooms that they desire the most, but an allocation should only be made if no other employee with a higher priority for that room desires the same room. **Example:** employee 1 wants room A, then B, then C, while employee 2 wants room B, then A, then C. Room A prefers employee 2, then 1, room B employee 1, then 2, and room C employee 2, then 1. Say room B is full. Since room A prefers employee 2 most, then allocate to A and emp1 to room C.

Comment: What are the values of $V$ in your example?

Comment: Let's say $V_{1A}$ = 3,  $V_{1B}$ = 5,  $V_{1C}$ = 1,  $V_{2A}$ =  4, $V_{2B}$ = 2  and $V_{2c}$ = 3. In practice I will have roughly 40 rooms and 500 employees, each room with a given capacity.

Comment: For these values of $V$, the resulting conflict constraints are$x_{1,A} + x_{2,B} \le 1$,
$x_{1,A} + x_{2,C} \le 1$,
$x_{1,C} + x_{2,B} \le 1$,
$x_{2,B} + x_{1,A} \le 1$,
$x_{2,B} + x_{1,C} \le 1$.  For example, the first one prevents employee 1 from getting room $A$ over employee 2.  The $V(e_2,r_2)<V(e_2,r_1)$ condition mans that employee $e_2$ would rather have room $r_1$ than $r_2$.

Comment: Not sure if you meant to write $x_{1,A} + x_{2,B} \leq 1$ twice, but I'm not sure if you understand me correctly. You say _The (2,2)<(2,1) condition means that employee 2 would rather have room 1 than 2_, but what it **actually** means is that room $r_1$ wants $e_2$ more than room $r_2$ - does that make sense and change your answer? Each employee has a preferred top three rooms, say $B^{1}_e$ is the index of the most preferred room for a given employee, $B^{2}_e$ second, and so on, but that is different from the ranking $V_{er}$ a given room has for a given employee.

Comment: Yes, that same constraint arises twice because it is triggered by two different conditions.  I was interpreting $V_{e,r}$ as a valuation, not a preference.  In any case, you can enforce whatever rules you want to define a conflict between $(e_1,r_1)$ and $(e_2,r_2)$, and the constraint $x_{e_1,r_1}+x_{e_2,r_2}\le 1$ will enforce that the conflict cannot happen.

Comment: But that implies that only one of $x_{e1,r1}$ and $x_{e2,r2}$ can be one, right? And that is not necessarily true, because a feasible solution might be having $e_1$ in room $r_1$ and $e_2$ in room $r_2$

Comment: Yes, the constraint prevents both variables from being 1, but only for the conflicts $(e_1,r_1,e_2,r_2)$ that you want to prevent.